# Buttons in Alert.alert() on Android goes upside down. (React-Native)

Tags: react-native

Am I only one who faces the issue that Buttons in Alert.alert() on Android go upside down? The last button goes to the top. I mean the order of buttons.

(iOS and Android tablet are OK)

I can't find any issues or question about this.

## Edit

I brought source code here.

```
    Alert.alert('Alert', 'Alert message',
        [
            {text:'Button 1', onPress:() => WHATEVER},
            {text:'Button 2', onPress:() => WHATEVER},
            {text:'Button 3', onPress:() => WHATEVER}
        ]);
```

Button 3 will go to top only on Android.

Comment: What buttons? OK and Cancel?

Comment: @木大白易 When you set more than two buttons, you can see it goes upside down. last button will go top and first button will go last.

Comment: At most three buttons (neutral, negative, positive) on Android, and  ignore rest.Can you show more details so that we can know about more clearly, like your code.

Comment: @木大白易 I put my code as an edit. It's just simply coded.

Comment: All right, I have tried your code, it seems to work fine without the kind of situation you're saying.

Comment: @木大白易 Thanks for taking your time. but you don't see any of this? Please check this image. https://imgur.com/a/zgu6u

Comment: @木大白易 What kind device or emulator did you try with?

Comment: I checked the image you have uploaded, I think the key is the `text` of Buttons you set is too long.it'll work fine if you only keep text `Button 1` just like the code you put.Maybe you can go to github to mention an issue.

Comment: @木大白易 Thanks. Maybe I have to post it.